# How can I add a changing value to a plot in excel?

Tags: excel

I currently have a plot in its own tab to have a clean look, but I want to display a value overlayed on the plot. This value changes depending on inputs so I don't want to just put a frozen text box there. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question, you want to have dynamic content in a text box?

Create a new text box. Do not add text to it. Click the text box, then in the address bar, put the reference to the cell which contains the text. Example: `=Sheet1!A1`.